# twilio connect within salesforce

Tags: salesforce, twilio, twilio-api

I would like to add twilio connect button to my salesforce app, 
The issue I am facing is what to do with the AUTHORIZE URL, As I need it to return ( after authorization)back to user salesforce.

Any solution ?

Comment: You've given very little context about your problem. Do you have an app built on the salesforce platform? Does it have a URL at all? Are you using Twilio connect as an [authentication provider](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_sfdc.htm&type=0)?

Comment: You could try asking this over on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/.